# Automatic message send without user confirmation in cordova android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have implemented sending message from my application using [this plugin](https://github.com/aharris88/phonegap-sms-plugin). It will open the default sms app in the phone with my message content and number but  i need send the sms automatically without prompting default sms app ,is there any way to achieve this in cordova?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the solution just leave the `Intent` as empty will get the desired result.

```
        var intent =''; //leave this empty for sending sms automatically
        var message='Test message';
        sms.send(number, message, intent, success, error)
```